# Django jQuery checkbox select/deselect all objects

Tags: jquery, checkbox, server

Has anyone come across with the jquery problem when running django on apache?

Specifically, the checkbox that selects and deselects all objects in admin page does not work properly (it works on django server). Here's the message from firebug:

> Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented
>   instead. jquery.min.js:1248:0
>
> TypeError: $(...).attr(...).parent is not a function

contrib/admin/static/admin/js/actions.js

```
$(actionCheckboxes).prop("checked", checked)
            .parent().parent().toggleClass(options.selectedClass, checked);
    },
```

Comment: Your Javascript / jQuery code only depends on your browser. The webserver have no influence in the client-side.

Comment: Well, that makes sense but as i said, i use the same browser when running the project locally from django server... Afterall everybody that has access to the particular web page faces the same problem (from their browser).

Comment: Are you using a newer version of jquery with an older django?

Comment: jquery 1.7.1. django 1.3 (also tested on 1.6)

Comment: if any of you has a deployed django application, it would be good to know what behavior you get when selecting and deselecting all objects in admin page...

Comment: ...anybody help here?

Comment: It seems that there is a bug in actions.min.js which is used when DEBUG is False. That's why in dev environments it behaves correctly (because actions.js is used). It would be good to know if we can impose actions.js even in production.